# a simple css issue about overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

This is my css content :-

```
   <style type = "text/css">
       li
    {
        display:inline;
    }
    .carousel
    {
        position:absolute; 
        white-space:nowrap;

    }
    .sliderGallery
    {
        width:800px;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:100px;

    }
 </style>
```

This is my html content :-

```
 <div id="sliderGallery" class = "sliderGallery">

        <ul id = "carousel" class="carousel">
            <li>
                <img src ="Images/1.jpg" />
            </li>

            <li>
                        <img src ="Images/2.jpg" />


            </li>

            <li>
                    <img src ="Images/3.jpg" />

            </li>

            <li>
                        <img src ="Images/4.jpg" />

            </li>

            <li>
                        <img src ="Images/5.jpg" />

            </li>

            <li>
                                <img src ="Images/6.jpg" />

            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

As you can see i have set `overflow:hidden` but still, my content is being displayed if it is more than `800px`. Where am i wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding a height to the div too?

Also try removing position:absolute; on the carousel.

Comment: Yep. If you don't have a specified height, the container will just expand.

Comment: Hi, Sorry. It still doesn't work :(. I am posting the edited code.

Comment: Then it works. However i want it to be absolute only. Since i am manipulating `left` property of css using jquery. And unfortunately left property only works when position is absolute. I am actually developing a carousel.

Comment: Then set the overflow hidden and height/width on the carousel ul, or add position: relative to the sliderGallery div.

Comment: No i don't want to set `overflow:hidden` on ul. Please see this link :- http://www.apple.com/mac/ . See the carousel on top. If i set overflow:hidden on ul then how am i going to show the rest of `<li>` when slider is moved left and right. Please give some idea to tweak the container. I can't set overflow:hidden on ul. It works but then my whole application stops working. :(

Comment: Did you add position: relative; to the div?

Comment: Great! You finally did my job. Voted. But why should i set it to positon:relative? Isn't it postion:relative by default?

Comment: You would think so! But no, always add position: relative on the parent of the absolutely positioned element. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing .sliderGallery to #sliderGallery in your CSS

Comment: Oops! sorry i forgot to add classname. I changed it in my post. But still it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Danixd above should be correct: setting position:relative on .sliderGallery (the div) will make the ul slide around inside it.  Currently, it is sliding around relative to the outer container (or body if you don't have one).  You can also try specifying an explicit width for the li.